# Differentiability by quotient ring of continuous functions at point

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, general-topology

Let's take quotient ring of continuous functions at point: $Ca/(o(1)*(x-a)) := Ca/o(x-a)$, where $o(1)$ - ideal of functions converges to zero at a. Easy to verify, that classes of differentiable functions form subring $\{[f(a) + f'(a)(x-a)]\}$ in $Ca/o(x-a)$ with dimension 2 - isomorphic to ring of dual numbers.

I wonder about structure of the rest classes. How to prove or contradict that class of non differentiable at point functions can't be equal $[t+kx]$ for any $t, k$? I only found, it's equivalent to say that $\frac{f-f(a)-t}{x-a}$ diverges at a, for non differentiable function $f$, for any $t$. I couldn't proof it, but couldn't find counterexample either.

Further questions are - what can be said about structure of such classes and dimension of $Ca/o(x-a)$ in general. May be you can suggest any book, where considered structure of $Ca/o(x-a)$?

Comment: $f$ is differentiable at $a$ iff $\exists k\in\Bbb R,\;f(x)=f(a)+(x-a)k+o(x-a),$ which is clearly equivalent to  $\exists b,k\in\Bbb R,\;f(x)=b+(x-a)k+o(x-a),$ i.e. to  $\exists t,k\in\Bbb R,\;[f]=[x\mapsto t+kx].$

Comment: @Anne Bauval, can u please explain why it follows that $f$
  is differentiable from yous second statement for $b \neq 0$

Comment: $b=0$ or $\ne0$ is irrelevant. If $f(x)=b+(x-a)k+o(x-a)$ then $b=\lim_af=f(a).$

Comment: @Anne Bauval, yes, its clear for differentiable function. I want to prove, that $f(x) \neq f(a)+(x−a)k+o(x−a)$ implies $\forall b, k\ f(x)\neq b+(x−a)k+o(x−a)$, or find the counterexample.

Comment: I did prove it in the previous comment (by contrapositive), without assuming a priori that $f$ was differentiable.

Comment: @Anne Bauval, got it, thanks!